# The parameter is not applied in the sam template

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, aws-cloudformation, sam

First of all, I ask for your patience that I am not familiar with English.

I am trying to deploy a serverless app through AWS' Codepipiline feature. However, in the codebuild stage, the sam template does not work properly. Below are some of my templates.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Parameters:
  filename:
    Type: String
    Default: test
Description: !Ref filename
```

Obviously, despite the declaration of the filename parameter, I get the following error:

```
Template format error: Every Description member must be a string.
```

And the template applied to the stack is as follows.

```
Description:
  Fn::Ref: filename
```

But what I want is the following output.

```
Description: test
```

There is also a problem with the sam deploy parameter "--paramater-overrides", but this doesn't work, so there's no progress.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are doing? "You can reference parameters from the Resources and Outputs sections of the same template. " from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html).

Comment: @Marcin I want to set up CodeUri dynamically via sam deploy --parameter-overrides command. However, the parameters were not passed, so I am testing.

Comment: I mean with the `Description`? Description of what? A parameter, or a template? What do you mean when you write `Description:   Fn::Ref: filename`? That it works?

Comment: @Marcin This is the description of the app, which can be viewed in the Application menu of the Lambda menu. Not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [AWS SAM Template Anatomy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy.html), you will find that:

> Description (optional)  This section **corresponds directly** with the Description section of AWS CloudFormation templates.

> Parameters (optional) This section **corresponds directly** with the Parameters section of AWS CloudFormation templates.

Subsequently, you **can't reference a parameter in a Description**. This is [because](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#parameters-section-structure-referencing):

> You can reference parameters from the **Resources and Outputs** sections of the same template.